# JSONP not working for certain links (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to use the GovTrack API. This code works:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/bill/76416?format=jsonp'
});
```

But this code doesn't:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/bill?format=jsonp'
});
```

I get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST) http://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/person?format=jsonp&callback=jQuery110209814499213825911_1381645302221&_=1381645302222
```

I'm guessing it's a bad request because of `_=1381645302222`, but I don't know how to fix it. When I go to the links they load the JSON fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is adding an additional parameter `_=xyz`(`http://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/bill?format=jsonp&callback=jQuery191010857695830054581_1381645903345&_=1381645903346`) to the request to disable caching of the get request

It looks like that particular request does not like the `_`(cache disable) parameter.

Try

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/bill?format=jsonp',
    cache: true
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rGEtr/)